# C++ find a sentence in list<word>

Tags: c++, boost, std

I'm trying to find an elegant way to find some text ex. `"hello world"` from the sentence `"I compiled my first hello world. It works!"`

But the sentence is a `std::list<word>` with some metadata.

```
Class Word
{
  std::string m_word;
  Location ... (X,Y in a picture)
  ....
}
```

Just wondering if there is nice way to do that with some std or boost functions rather than my 2 ugly loops. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the two ugly loops?

Comment: I swear this isn't homework! (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`std::search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) together with a custom predicate that only compares the `m_word` member:

```
bool wordsEqual(const Word& a, const Word& b) {
    return a.getWord() == b.getWord();
}

// ...
Word needle[] = { "hello", "world" };
list<Word>::iterator it = search(lst.begin(), lst.end(),
                                 needle, needle + 2,
                                 wordsEqual);
```

This code assumes a `getWord` method and a constructor `Word(const char*)` for the array initialization.

Comment: It seams perfect. thanks a lot!! Can you explain why i need a Word::Word(const char*) ?

Comment: @ablm: For the array initialization to work: `Word needle[] = { "hello", "world" };`

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOH!! LOL. I thought you mean for std::search. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [`std::search`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/search/).

```
string pattern[] = {"hello","world"};
list<string>::iterator it = search(x.begin(),x.end(), pattern, pattern + 1);
```

Where `x` is your list. You'll probably have to provide your own binary predicate.